# Geth private net not mining

Tags: geth

My geth private net is not mining. I've tried setting the etherbase and when I call on it right after and it says true, it shows as undefined. On the left is the geth console on the right is the geth JS console. The geth console just is stuck on "commit new mining work" and I get the feeling that is because of the etherbase issue.

[image]

Comment: Use `eth.coinbase` to check etherbase account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.)`.setEtherbase()` is not an method of the personal object. It's a method of the miner object. That way `miner.setEtherbase('0x4...')` will work.

2.) `miner.start()` has normally no output. You console interpreted this as `null`

3.) to verify your account, you should use `eth.coinbase` instead of `miner.etherbase`